# Denial of Service http-proxy: Ionic Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack-dev-server, http-proxy-middleware

I've got Ionic Angular project, and today after i installing some `npm` packages,

it shows `found 3 vulnerabilities (1 low, 2 high)` message at the end.

And when i run `npm audit` it returned this,

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ http-proxy                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ No patch available                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-server >         │
│               │ http-proxy-middleware > http-proxy                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1486                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Denial of Service                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ http-proxy                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ No patch available                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ karma [dev]                                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ karma > http-proxy                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1486                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ yargs-parser                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=13.1.2 <14.0.0 || >=15.0.1 <16.0.0 || >=18.1.2             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @angular-devkit/build-angular [dev]                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-server > yargs > │
│               │ yargs-parser                                                 │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

and then i ran `npm audit --prod`,

```
                       === npm audit security report ===                        

found 0 vulnerabilities
 in 78 scanned packages
```

does it mean, it doesn't affect in production environment ?

And once i access the given link in audit report for more info, it says,

> No fix is currently available. Consider using an alternative package until a fix is made available.

So is there any alternatives available for `http-proxy` package ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run `npm audit fix` then it will be solved by now. Just had the same issue but there is a fix for this issue already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it mean, it doesn't affect in production environment ?

Yes, it will not affect your prod environment. `http-proxy` is only used in your dev dependency as you can see in the row "Depenceny of".

> So is there any alternatives available for http-proxy package ?

I don't think so since Angular uses it itself. We have to wait until there is an official fix.